# Android - can't set margins for custom button

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Holo.Light theme and I am trying to make buttons not be transparent. I accomplished that, but now I want to add margin to the buttons and I have not been able to do that. Here is the button xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">

        <shape>

            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#E3E3E3" />

            <corners android:radius="4dip" />

            <margin
                android:left="15dp"
                android:right="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>

        <shape>

            <solid android:color="#edeff1" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#E3E3E3" />

            <corners android:radius="4dip" />

            <margin
                android:left="15dp"
                android:right="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

How can I add margin? My current setting doesn't render.

Thanks!

Comment: This is clearly explained in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension (also note that `dp` and `dip` are exactly the same)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not add it to your button in XML?

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="xyz"
android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
android:layout_marginleft="15dp"
android:layout_marginleft="15dp" />
```